# Keypress exceptions on restricted characters

Tags: c#, keypress

How can I allow the space bar to be used in a textbox that is restricted to numbers only?

```
 private void CLimitTxt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You can only enter numbers within this textbox", "Error");
            CLimitTxt.Text = "";
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Would I need to declare a var regex with an exception perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
private void CLimitTxt_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (!char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) && !e.KeyChar == ' ')
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You can only enter numbers within this textbox", "Error");
        CLimitTxt.Text = "";
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: That still gives the error when the space bar is pressed down

Comment: Seems like I can get it to work with space using && char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) but it won't let backspace be used then I thought space and backspace were both controls?

Comment: @Topher From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/18zw7440%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "_Control characters are non-printing and formatting characters, such as ACK, BEL, CR, FF, LF, and VT. _"

try `if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space))`

Comment: @Topher `if (!(char.IsNumber(e.KeyChar) || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Space || e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back))`

Comment: Thanks that works. Is it ordered somehow as I tried it as back first then space and it didnt work?

Comment: @Topher The order shouldn't matter